# using cypress chainable command in if/else

Tags: typescript, cypress

how to use chainable command mixed with if/else logic? any one know how to clean up the code as following? I do not want to have duplicated code `.trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});` in both if/else. the only option I can think of is using return in logic. but it does not work

```
    const selectedOption = 'I am option'
    cy.get('.my-selector')
      .contains(selectedOption)
      .scrollIntoView()
      .then(($option) => {
        if ($option.find('input').length === 1) {
          cy.wrap($option.find('input')).trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});
        } else {
          cy.wrap($option).trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});
        }
      });
```

using `return`

```
      .then(($option) => {
        if ($option.find('input').length === 1) {
          return cy.wrap($option.find('input'));
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the use case is? Maybe there's a better solution that doesn't involve conditional testing, since it's not ideal to do conditional testing

Comment: I need to use the same function to click the option from two typeahead component. However, option with checkbox from one component and one does not

Comment: It does seem ok for me as a conditional testing, apart from this - `.trigger('focus', {force: true})` seems redundant if you will use `.click({force:true})`. I would separate it in 2 cases if possible though if it is not api reliant, but reliant on your actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper function to get the correct target,

```js
const getTarget = ($el) => {
  const $input = $el.find('input');
  return $input.length ? $input : $el;
}

cy.get('.my-selector')
  .contains(selectedOption)
  .scrollIntoView()
  .then(($option) => {
    cy.wrap(getTarget($option)).trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});
  });

// another syntax

cy.get('.my-selector')
  .contains(selectedOption)
  .scrollIntoView()
  .then($option => getTarget($option))
  .trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});
```

Or with a custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('optionTarget', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  const $input = subject.find('input');
  return $input.length ? $input : subject;
})

cy.get('.my-selector')
  .contains(selectedOption)
  .scrollIntoView()
  .optionTarget().trigger('focus', {force: true}).click({force: true});
```